# How to properly implement quota reached functionality in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, quota

I was wondering on how to properly and cleanly implement quota reached functionality in my SaaS depending on the plan the workspace is on.

Solution 1 (my first pick):

I was thinking of using the fail early principle and checking the user quota inside of the rails controller.

```
 # ClientsController
 before_action :check_quota_limit, only: [:create]

 # ApplicationController
 rescue_from MySaaS::QuotaLimitReached, with: :quota_limit_reached
```

Solution 2:

The other solution I was thinking of is doing it inside of the model. But this has a few drawbacks since you can easily bump into N+1 queries while validating + you don't always have the current user available through a model. Which would result in multiple queries just to be able to save this model.

```
# Client
class Client
  validates :quota_limit_reached
end
```

I'm leaning towards solution 1 but I just want to see if anyone else has something that didn't cross my mind yet.

Comment: You havent actually told us what its a quota of.

Comment: A quota is pretty clear. It is a hard limit a user will have depending on the plan he is on.

Example: Plan 1 allows the creation of 5 clients, Plan 2 allows 20 clients, Plan 3 allows unlimited clients.

Comment: It might be more efficient to check and flag to the user the fact that they are at their quota limit in the ClientController#new page, rather than allow them to try to create a client and only after their attempt to tell them that creating another client would exceed their quota.

Comment: @LesNightingill Well yes thats my question I'd like an answer to. Note this is a SaaS with an API. So `new` doesn't really exist in the context of the api.

A user calls the `create` method on my clients controller and should be notified that his/her quota has been reached.

My best option would be solution 1 but I was wondering if any other solutions exist.